# Is it a good practice to alter html ids?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my example, I have a div with an id "foo1Closed". When I click on "foo1Closed" I want numerous elements to be changed within the div (e.g. Height, Width, Color, Visibility, etc.).

One way I accomplished this is by coding two styles for each element in my .css file. For example, one style for "foo1Closed" and one for "foo1Opened". Like:

```
#foo1Closed {
   visibility:hidden;
}
#foo1Opened {
    visibility:visible;
}
```

I then use a JavaScript function to change these ids, like:

```
document.getElementById("foo1Opened").id = "foo1Closed";
```

Since I am unaware about potential drawbacks with this approach, I was hoping someone could answer if this is an "okay" way to accomplish this interactivity, or if I should instead modify the style directly through JavaScript like so:

```
document.getElementById("foo1Opened").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Obviously, one solution is going to have more CSS code and one is going to have more JavaScript code. What I am NOT aware of, is which one is more efficient (as far as performance and/or modeling a project is concerned).

Reworded question: Since IDs are used to identify a specific object (meaning they typically shouldn't be altered), is there a different way to accomplish this without editing the IDs and also not relying on changing every element manually through JavaScript?

Comment: Your better off using css classes.

Comment: From a technical standpoint there's nothing wrong with it. You can do it and it will work. However, this isn't typically done with IDs but classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you should use a class

```
#foo1.closed {
   visibility:hidden;
}
#foo1.opened {
    visibility:visible;
}

document.getElementById("foo1").setAttribute("class","closed");
document.getElementById("foo1").setAttribute("class","opened");
```

Or you can build functions on top of this (but don't take my code, avoid use of globals)

```
... CSS ...

var foo1 = document.getElementById("foo1");

var openFoo = function() {
    foo1.setAttribute("class","opened")
}
var closeFoo = function() {
    foo1.setAttribute("class","closed")
}
```

Comment: as @Simon Verhoeven said , jQuery is a perfect match for this type of DOM manipulation

Comment: This seems so nice. So keeping the stylistic changes within the CSS is a good practice, but instead of changing the ID I use a class and set attributes. Thanks, exactly the type of answer I was looking for!

Comment: note that jQuery has .show() and .hide() methods

Comment: True, but he also wants to change width\colour etc so add\removeClass is probably more suited for his intentions down the line if he is planning on using jQuery.

Comment: Not sure if i would change colors of a disappeared div but yes, at lower level you get more control on things, agreed

Answer (score 5):

My personal preference is to use jQuery to add\remove a class instead of changing IDs.
Doing the latter is just asking for trouble down the line when you want to achieve more effects.

Something along the lines of:

```
$("#foo1").removeClass("class1").addClass("class2");
```

Or however you want to achieve it conditionally.

Comment: Using an entire library like jQuery to change a class (or ID) seems like a little overkill, no?

Comment: @j08691 it is if that's all you're doing with it. But as I said, it's my personal preference and I am usually also using jQuery for a lot of other purposes.

Comment: Nice, quick and simple solution. I was thinking the ID route was a messy idea, glad I asked the question. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Think of the ID of the element as a unique identifier that should not change over time, while a CSS class represents a description or meta-data about the element that may change over time.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick and dirty answer:** No, it's very bad to change IDs.

IDs are the **IDentifiers** of your element. You shouldn't use IDs which point to the styles of your element. Doing so is not semantic and turn the refactoring process harder. I know you're just starting with HTML/JS/CSS, but this is important to know :)

For the purpose you described in your question, the best would be to use classes. For example:

```
.opened {
   visibility: visible;
}
.closed {
   visibility: hidden;
}

<div id="foo1" class="opened"></div>
```

Then, in your JavaScript...

```
document.getElementById("foo1").setAttribute("class", "opened");
document.getElementById("foo1").setAttribute("class", "closed");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that changing the element's id would be "okay" but would not agree with doing it.  The purpose of the id is to identify the element.  So changing the id should really be changing the element.

Rather than changing the id, why not add and remove a class.

From a semantic point of view you are changing the properties of a specific part of the page, thus changing the class makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You **should not change the "id" attribute**.
**Use the "class" attribute instead**. 

For example:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    div.closed {
        display:none;
    }
    div.opened {
        display:inline;
    }

</style>

<div id="foo1" class="opened">...</div>
```

In your javascript function use the following:

```
    var foo1 = document.getElementById("foo1");

    foo1.className="closed";
```

Try to avoid changing the class attribute by this way:
document.getElementById("foo1").setAttribute("class","closed");

You should use the **className** property of the DOM Element

Answer (score 0):

You could change the class instead of the id, and set in your styles to show or hide the element depending on it's class.

Answer (score -1):

you should use classes, not ids

Comment: And the reasoning for that is what?

Comment: obviously because classes are made to qualify thigs and ids are made to identify them.